# Getting Feedburner Subscriber With CURL

Tags: php, curl, subscription, feedburner

I'm using FeedBurner Awareness API. XML data like this :

```
<rsp stat="ok">
−
<!--
This information is part of the FeedBurner Awareness API. If you want to hide this information, you may do so via your FeedBurner Account.
-->
−
<feed id="9n66llmt1frfir51p0oa367ru4" uri="teknoblogo">
<entry date="2011-01-15" circulation="11" hits="18" reach="0"/>
</feed>
</rsp>
```

I want to get **circulation** data (11) . I'm using this code:

```
$whaturl="https://feedburner.google.com/api/awareness/1.0/GetFeedData?uri=teknoblogo";

//Initialize the Curl session
$ch = curl_init();

//Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//Set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $whaturl);

//Execute the fetch
$data = curl_exec($ch);

//Close the connection
curl_close($ch);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$fb = $xml->feed->entry['circulation'];
echo $fb;
echo "OK";
```

But, returned data is blank. There isn't any error. Only return **OK** . How can i solve this ?

EDIT : echo $data; returning blank, too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `http` instead of `https`?

For this case, I don't think that there will be any problems using `http`.

Some web hosting providers and some servers have SSL disabled for cURL.

You might want to [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731117/error-using-php-curl-with-ssl-certificates) about using cURL + SSL.

Comment: Thank you. But still same problem .

Comment: Actually, it worked for me (`https`). You may have to check if the server can access the resource or not.

Comment: Can you try a `print_r` of `curl_getinfo`?

Comment: added this code **print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));** , nothing returned. BUT code start working. It returning 11 . I'm deleting **print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));** code but still working :D I can't understand . My problem is solved for now, but i can't understand how solved.