# OneAuth Blank Callback

Tags: php, oauth, laravel

I'm using Laravel and OneAuth to build a web application. The user can sign in with his/her Twitter or GitHub account.

This actually works perfectly on my local dev server (with the exception of GitHub because the callback URLs don't match localhost), but when I've uploaded it to production, I get a blank page (`/connect/callback/twitter`).

Anyone else experienced this with OneAuth?

There are no errors in the error log, and the page has a `200` status code.

**Local server:**

- Mac OS X 10.8
- MAMP
- PHP 5.4

**Production:**

- CentOS 5
- Apache + PHP 5.3

Comment: Error reporting is enabled as far as I can tell. Errors get logged for everything else...

Comment: the callback url should be connect/callback/twitter

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It is connect/callback/twitter, it was a typo.

Comment: Does it work with Github on production server? I don't see any reason why it's not working. unless your curl is not properly installed, which would cause SSL Certification issue.

Comment: It's the production server that's the issue. As far as I know, curl is ok since I can use it from the terminal without issues.

Comment: curl from terminal ~== curl from php. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10417888/1458318

Comment: Any solution to this? I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i had this problem and the work around for this is to manually register your controller instead of doing ,

```
Route::controller(Controller::detect());
```

Do this,

```
Route::controller('connect');
```

FYI: If you are using nested controller the order in which you register matters.