# SSL Certificate request with cURL

Tags: php, curl, ssl, https, bots

I'm writing a betting bot in PHP and the bet house requires a SSL Certificate being sent for automated connections.

I've got all kinds of self-signed certificates to use: **cert.crt, cert.pem, cert.p12** and also a key **cert.key** and I'm using curl to establish the login connection however I can't seem to get the curl parameters right for the connection.

With the following command line I can establish a successful connection:

```
curl -q -k --cert cert.crt --key cert.key https://api.domain.com/certificatelogin/endpoint -d "username=UUUUUUU&password=XXXXXXX" -H "X-Application: appKey"
```

And this one works too:

```
curl -q -k --cert cert.pem https://api.domain.com/certificatelogin/endpoint -d "username=UUUUUUU&password=XXXXXXX" -H "X-Application: appKey"
```

The PHP code I'm currently using is as follows:

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.domain.com/certificatelogin/endpoint");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'X-Application: ' . $appKey,
        'Accept: */*',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "path/to/cert/cert.pem");

    $postData = 'username=UUUUUUUUU&password=XXXXXXXXXXX';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    echo 'Response: ' . json_encode($response);
```

And after trying so many combinations with **.crt** and **.key** can't seem to make anything work at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731117/error-using-php-curl-with-ssl-certificates

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort Robert, however it turned out the problem wasn't with curl at all, just the betting house didn't allow any connections from within that area of the US where the server is. But thank you once again for the quick answer.