# Curl sending form to https

Tags: php, curl, https

I'm trying to send image and some more options to the server using curl, but I don't know why it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
<?php

header('Location: https://www.reporo.com/analytics/inventory-advertiser-banner.php?clientid=xxxx&campaignid=xxxx&type=smrc');

$uploadUrl = "C:\wamp\www\autofill\demo_300x250.png";
$uploadUrl = "@$uploadUrl";


$post_data['description'] = 'Name';
$post_data['url'] = 'http://www.url.pl';
$post_data['campaignid'] = xxxxx;
$post_data['clientid'] = xxxxx;
$post_data['bannertext'] = 'some text';
$post_data['upload_smrc'] = $uploadUrl;

    foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value)
{
    $post_items[] = urlencode($key) . '=' . urlencode($value);
}
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.reporo.com/analytics/inventory-advertiser-banner.php?clientid=xxxxx&campaignid=xxxxx&type=smrc");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.reporo.com/analytics/inventory-advertiser-banner-update.php');
$upload_result = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

Indexes in $post_data are right. The form is in the same link as CURLOPT_REFERER. Field action i form contain: inventory-advertiser-banner-update.php .

Moreover I can't login to this site using curl but when I logged before, redirect works so it should work.

Is it possible that this site site can't be used curl ? I ask because before I had problem with login which I didn't resolve and now this.

Maybe there is a way to workaround ?

Greetings.

Comment: What are the curl errors you are getting. Might be due to security certificate issues. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521418/reading-ssl-page-with-curl-php and http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are likely to have problem with `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`

Try

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: Please note that [disabling VERIFYPEER or VERIFYHOST makes the connection vulnerable to MITM attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13742121/372643).

Answer (score 1):

Turning SSL peer verification off is not good idea.
If you want to use SSL peer verification you may use next solution on Windows globally for all applications:

1. Download file with root certificates from here:
   http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
2. Add to php.ini:

`curl.cainfo=C:/path/to/ca-bundle.crt`

that's all magic, CURL can now verify certificates.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the cause, but you need to `urlencode` POST keys and values if you're building the POST string manually.

```
foreach ($post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = urlencode($key) . '=' . urlencode($value);
}
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);
```

Otherwise you'll get all kinds of unexpected results if any of your keys or values contains `&`, `=` etc.

That being said, you can use the array directly with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` instead:

`curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);`