# php curl to check ssl connection

Tags: php, jquery, ssl, curl

Would like some help with my php curl connection - in my firebug console I keep getting this error

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: host in **C:\xampp\htdocs\labs\test2\get.php** on line **6**
>   Error:3  malformed

AJAX code:

```
    var hostName = $("input#host").val();
dataString = hostName;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "get.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",
```

PHP CURL code:

```html
<?php
if($fp = tmpfile())
{
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_GET['host']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_errno($ch)==0 or die("Error:".curl_errno($ch)." ".curl_error($ch));
    fseek($fp, 0);//rewind
    $str='';
    while(strlen($str.=fread($fp,8192))==8192);
    echo $str;
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

-- RESPONSE ---

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found Cache-Control: private Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Location: http://www.google.com.au/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=VbwrVa_RFsPu8wfN54HYBQ Content-Length: 262 Date: Mon, 13 Apr 2015 12:53:41 GMT Server: GFE/2.0 Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=0.5 * Rebuilt URL to: www.google.com/ * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache * Trying 216.58.220.100... * Connected to www.google.com (216.58.220.100) port 80 (#0) > HEAD / HTTP/1.1 Host: www.google.com Accept: */* < HTTP/1.1 302 Found < Cache-Control: private < Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 < Location: http://www.google.com.au/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=VbwrVa_RFsPu8wfN54HYBQ < Content-Length: 262 < Date: Mon, 13 Apr 2015 12:53:41 GMT < Server: GFE/2.0 < Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=0.5 < * Connection #0 to host www.google.com left intact

Comment: Shouldn't it be `data: {host: hostName},` ?

Comment: What are you using `http_build_query` for? You're effectively setting `$url` to "`http://host=www.google.com`", which as curl says, is not a valid hostname.

Comment: yeah it should only pass the value which would be the URL. If i have `data {hostName],` i still get errors in the console `<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: host in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\labs\test2\get.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />Error:3 <url> malformed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http_build_query does not create a valid url but only formats the parameters array for your GET request.
You should do something like :

```
$url = "https://".$_REQUEST['host']."?"."{$query_string}";
```

In your example the resulting url will be

```
https://www.google.com?host=www.google.com
```

Note the "https"

Comment: sure thx for the suggestion.. i can a response but i think something is wrong still.. every site i test i get this response in console **Error:60 SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**

Comment: expected output can be seen here [link](http://www.zedwood.com/article/php-fetch-ssl-certificate-using-curl)

Comment: Look into your apache (or whatever) error log for the curl ssl output info.
As for the SSL certificate error, I am not sure but there is an answer there about that : 
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187946/60-ssl-certificate-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chainbool

You can either modify this line :
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

or install the correct certificates (depends on your platform).

Comment: i found the file i needed to reference and am one step closer `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'cacert.pem');` now getting this in the console log `Error:77 error setting certificate verify locations:` ..will keep looking

Comment: all done.. just had to set the path to the cacert.pem file in the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'c:\path\to\file\cacert.pem');` and now i get the ssl cert extract in the console :)

Comment: cacert.pem file can be downloaded from [link](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)

Comment: Great ! Happy you found the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your data string is wrong

```
dataString = hostName;
```

That will only contain the data

```
dataString = {"host":hostName};
```

That should pass the parameter `host` in your GET string

Comment: tried it and now get this error in firebug `Error:6 Could not resolve host: host=www.google.com`

Comment: Why are you setting the URL to the value of the query string? Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_GET['host']);`. I would not leave that code in production, however, as anyone could use your script to spam another site with requests.

Comment: okay, i updated my post with the php code with the changes you suggested.. i also included the response im getting. definetly an improvement but still not getting the desired outcome as seen here [link](http://www.zedwood.com/article/php-fetch-ssl-certificate-using-curl)

Comment: You're still not connecting over SSL. `Connected to www.google.com (216.58.220.100) port 80 (#0)` Port 80 is `http://`. You want 443, which is `https://`. You will either have to pass that in your GET or change your code to only accept `https` URLs

Comment: yup. if i use https:// it connects to 443 but gives this error `Error:60 SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` i seem to recall curl needs to be told where to reference the cerificate authorities file to trust the connection.. i will do some googling for it