# Why is Wamp server giving errors when I use Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I'm trying to use the API of a dutch site that's being used by schools in The Netherlands to keep track of the grades and other data of the students. You can find the documantation here: http://www.magister-api.nl/ (it's in Dutch).
I installed Wamp server and Composer, just like the documentation of the API tells. I also have the Curl PHP extension and Mcrypt PHP extension enabled in Wamp, just like the documentation tells. 
I have the composer.json file in the project root with:

```
{
   "require": {
      "stanvk/magister": "~2.0"
   }
}
```

I then executed Composer update.

The only code that I have is:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Magister\Magister;
use Magister\Models\Grade\Grade;

new Magister($school, $username, $password);

$grades = Grade::all();

foreach ($grades as $grade)
{
        echo $grade->CijferStr;
}
?>
```

It's the exact same code as given as example on the documentation website.

But when I then run it, I get these errors:

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpWmu.png)

I tried a lot to solve the problem, but I can't seem to figure it out. It's the first time I'm using composer and packagist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two errors are unrelated to composer or Wamp - you're simply using two variables that hasn't been defined, `$username` and `$password` (and possibly `$school`). The rest of the errors seems to stem from these having no value (the `Magister` object seems to try to request username.magister.net, and without a username .. that field is empty).

Provide the correct username and password and things will probably work as you expect.

Comment: I povided the correct information and defined the variables, but I'm still getting: https://gyazo.com/d4c0f5c561bcbf9ea2ff1ab6e812d554

Comment: You'll need to [set the `curl.cainfo` setting in your php.ini](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23585500/137650). This is a common issue under Windows with the current Wampserver builds at least.