# How can I convert data from POSTMAN into PHP Curl Request?

Tags: php, curl

I have an API in postman. I want to create a CURL Request and get proper response with it. This is my POSTMAN API.

[image]

I am successfully getting this response with it.

```
"{\"Request\":{\"state\":\"Manama\",\"address\":\"406 Falcon Tower\",\"address2\":\"Diplomatic Area\",\"city\":\"Manama\",\"country\":\"BH\",\"fullname\":\"Dawar Khan\",\"postal\":\"317\"},\"Response\":{\"status\":\"Success\",\"code\":100,\"message\":\"Address is verified\"}}"
```

Now I want to use this API Call inside my PHP Code. I used this code.

```
    $data = array(
        'Request' => 'ValidateAddress',
        'address' => test_input($form_data->address),
        'secondAddress' => test_input($form_data->secondAddress),
        'city' => test_input($form_data->city),
        'country' => test_input($form_data->country),
        'name' => test_input($form_data->name),
        'zipCode' => test_input($form_data->zipCode),
        'merchant_id' => 'shipm8',
        'hash' => '09335f393d4155d9334ed61385712999'
    );
    $data_string = json_encode($data);

    $url = 'myurl.com/';

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $json_result = json_decode($result, true);
    echo '<pre>';print_r($json_result);echo '</pre>';
```

But I can't see my $json_result. It just echoes `<pre></pre>` in the view. Can anyone guide me? Thanks in advance. I want to get my `Response`.

**UPDATE**

I used curl_error and it gives me the following error.

> Curl error: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Comment: Check whether Curl gives any error using [**`curl_error`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php). You can refer [**`this answer`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987006/how-to-catch-curl-errors-in-php#answer-3987037) to find error.

Comment: Have you tried the code generated by postman?

Comment: Curl error: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain @BhavikShah

Comment: You should check [**`this answer`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187946/60-ssl-certificate-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chainbool#answer-23585500). It has something to do with the certificate.

Comment: @BhavikShah I already checked it at it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @AliZia: Great. I have drafted an answer as well for others who might face same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer updated as per updated question.

There are two ways to solve this issue

**Lengthy, time-consuming yet clean**

1. Visit URL in web browser.
2. Open Security details.
3. Export certificate.
4. Change cURL options accordingly.

   ```
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/CAcerts/BuiltinObjectToken-EquifaxSecureCA.crt");
   ```

**Quick but dirty**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

We are configuring `cURL` to accept any server(peer) certificate. This isn’t optimal from a security point of view.

Excerpt from [very detailed and precise article](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/) with screenshots for better understanding. Kindly refer the same before actually implementing it in production site.

Comment: Can you tell me 1 last thing? What do I have to send in $data_string so that my response is successfully sent? I am not getting any response yet and errors that my parameters are missing.

Comment: @AliZia: I don't think, anything is missing in `$data_string`. But, you should verify that you have passed all required parameters. I mean, there is nothing wrong technically. May be, you are missing something some required parameters for successful request and response.

Comment: @AliZia: Or you should try to test with static data in source. Just check, whether everything works fine with static data. If yes, then there is something wrong with the data or used functions.

Comment: @AliZia: cURL Worked with static text??

Answer (score 33):

> It is Very Simple Just Click on Code you will get the code in php.

you will get the code in many language like php,java,ruby,javascript,nodejs,shell,swift,pythom,C# etc. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: in some different postman version:  code icon '</>' is used