# Converting a Postman request to curl

Tags: php, curl, postman

I am calling my Java webservice (POST request) via Postman in the following manner which works perfectly fine (i.e. I can see my records getting inserted into the database):

[image]

And, here's how the contents inside the `Headers(1)` tab look like:

[image]

Instead of calling it via Postman, I have to call the same request in PHP using cURL. I am wondering if there's a way to export this command to a `curl` command so that I could use it in my PHP code? I have found the opposite approach at many places online where someone is asking to convert a curl based request to Postman but couldn't figure out how to do the opposite.

I found this question for curl to Postman: [Simulate a specific CURL in PostMan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957943/simulate-a-specific-curl-in-postman)

Comment: The last time I used Postman I remember it showed the curl command for cli somewhere. Regardless, using phpcurl to post a json body is quite straightforward. The json string as the postfield and set the appropriate header

Comment: Is there a way to do this for Insomnia?

Comment: Seems like all answers are correct answer just mentioning different version of UIs. :)

Answer (score 1316, accepted):

[image: Open code window]

You can see the button `</>` **Code icon** in right side of the Postman app (attached screenshot).
**Press it** and you can get your code in many different languages including PHP cURL

[image: Code snippets window]

Comment: Thanks. I found similar thread here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632296/how-can-i-convert-data-from-postman-into-php-curl-request  . But it's showing lot of things like Postman-Token, Cache-Control. Do I need to include that?

Comment: Gracias Jose, this is amazing. @Coder no you don't need the Postman-Token and the Cache-Control header depends if you want to prevent cashing of the req or not. If you want always fresh content, include it.

Comment: Honestly, super impressed with the Hooli, I mean Google, team for making postman portable to curl

Answer (score 193):

Starting from `Postman 8` you need to visit here

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was confused where this button now at Postman 8.

Comment: only problem here is that the code panel was empty in my case in 8.0.4 - updating to 8.0.6 fixed this

Comment: Can you write this as text for those of us who can't access Imgur on our work network?

Comment: @user3067860 , this should help 
https://bernatskyys.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/converting-a-postman-request-to-curl.png

Comment: I hate this new UI, it takes up so much more memory on windows as well

Comment: To the user above, the button on the top right has a symbol that looks like: </>

Answer (score 33):

The first answer here works with the older versions of Postman. With the latest releases in 2021 the cURL can be found clicking this icon (circled in red)
[image]

Answer (score 11):

For those who use v7.36.5 for Ubuntu, or similar.
Instead of the `</>` icon, there is a clickable "Code" text:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Steps:

- Open Postman
- Open your request
- Select `</>` icon from right side bar
- Select cURL from dropdown (if not cURL is there by default)
- Copy the code and use.

Comment: that is exatly the same solution than the other 7 post, what brings new ?

Comment: Dear Ana, tried to be specific with the steps. Sorry if that seems redundant.

Answer (score 8):

If you're like me running MacOS and still have Postman v7, you have to click the ellipses here to find the code option

[image]

Comment: This ellipsis show only when you're using the side-by-side view and when the screen resolution doesn't allow for all the tabs to be shown at the same time. You can change the display at the bottom-right of the window.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a quick video demonstration [postman request to curl](http://youtu.be/L3m6cpQPsV0)

Latest version 8.x:

- Find **Code** symbol on the right side of the postman.
  [image]
- Select cURL from the dropdown.
  [image]

Answer (score 5):

Select `</>` **Code icon** from right side in Postman.

Answer (score 3):

[image]To extend the existing answers, there is an option to ***generate PHP ready cURL code*** if needed. With latest Postman, you will find dropdown for **PHP - cURL** and other languages.

See screenshot:

Answer (score 1):

For `Postman Version 7.36.5 (7.36.5)`

[image]

Comment: What about Postman 7.36.4?