# I need to fetch API to get a raw value from response same as the result in POSTMAN but fail?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, npm, fetch-api

I am new from here. Just stuck on some problem of fetching the data from frontend(react) to the raw value in JSON. For the login part, when I enter the email and password, supposedly the response are same as the result in POSTMAN, but i get the error. I am figure out this issue for almost one week. I would be appreciate for those who help me to solve on this issue. I will elaborate further on below about my situation:

Here is the response of API from Postman (supposedly I should get this response):
[image: The response of API from POSTMAN]

The result I get in the browser:

[image]

Source Code:

```
constructor (props){
  super(props);
  this.state ={
    loginEmail: '',
    loginPassword: ''
  }
  this.login = this.login.bind(this);
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

login(){
  PostData('api/users/login', this.state).then ((result) => {
    let responseJSON = result;
    console.log(responseJSON);
  });
}
```

PostData:

```
export function PostData(type, userData = {}){

    let BaseUrl = "https://ems-unimas-58134.herokuapp.com/"
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        fetch(BaseUrl+type,{
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(userData),
            Accept: 'application/json',
            // headers:{
            //   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            // }
          }).then(res => res.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            resolve(responseJson);
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.error('Error:', error);
        })

    });

}
```

Commend down here if anyone of you need more code.

Comment: uncomment the headers property. You can see which headers postman is using by clicking the Headers tab

Comment: Hi, @AngelSalazar thanks for comment here. But if I uncomment the headers, This error comes out "Access to fetch at 'https://ems-unimas-58134.herokuapp.com/api/users/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Comment: In postman, you can copy the script as fetch [can you see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432735/converting-a-postman-request-to-curl)

Comment: @kokoka then the problem is your server, you have to whitelist localhost

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to allow CORS.
You can read more about CORS in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)