# How to convert raw request into php post curl request

Tags: php, api, curl

I am trying to use outreach API for my PHP website. On outreach, this is request they mentioned:

POST https://api.outreach.io/api/v2/prospects

{
    "data": 
{
        "attributes": {
            "firstName": "Test_3",
            "lastName": "API"
        },
        "type": "prospect"
    }
}

In PHP , i converted this to following code but it gives error "Bad Request". Please help me what i am doing wrong, accessToken in below code is having correct value.

```
$urlCreateAccount = "https://api.outreach.io/api/v2/prospects";
$attributes = array("firstName"=> "Sally","lastName"=> "Biu");
$paramsCreateAccount = "type=prospect$attributes=".$attributes;
$headr[] = "Authorization:bearer $accessToken";

$curl = curl_init($urlCreateAccount);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $paramsCreateAccount);

$jsonResponseCreateAccount = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: You can try using POSTMAN to convert into PHP. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49433083/2609521

Answer (score 0):

I can really say what is wrong in code. But try once this code. I have taken sample json data **outreach api document**

```
$jsonData = "{
  "data": {
    "type": "prospect",
    "attributes": {
      "emails": ["sally.smith@acme.example.com"],
      "firstName": "Sally",
      "title": "CEO"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "account": {
        "data": {
          "type": "account",
          "id": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}";

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.outreach.io/api/v2/prospects",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>$jsonData,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json",
    "Authorization: Bearer <Access Token>",
    "Content-Type: text/plain"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Hope you will get your result. Also you can use postman to test the api first and from there you can take out the code fro the desired language

Comment: Thanks for your help. Below part is giving error, can you please point out what is wrong with your jsonData part:

$jsonData = "{
  "data": {
    "type": "prospect",
    "attributes": {
      "emails": ["sally.smith@acme.example.com"],
      "firstName": "Sally",
      "title": "CEO"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "account": {
        "data": {
          "type": "account",
          "id": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}";

Comment: The code for `$jsonData` has nested double quotes, try changing the outermost quotes to single quotes `$jsonData = '{` and `}';`.  Ideally you should build the data as an array and then JSON encode the result, but try this first.

Comment: try out this one
$jsonData = '{
  "data": {
    "type": "prospect",
    "attributes": {
      "emails": ["sally.smith@acme.example.com"],
      "firstName": "Sally",
      "title": "CEO"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "account": {
        "data": {
          "type": "account",
          "id": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}';

Answer (score 0):

Its expecting JSON, so you need to POST JSON. Something like this...

```
$data = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $access,'Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```