# convert a postman post request to get token into a curl request

Tags: curl, post, request, postman

I have a post request that works fine with postman and I try to convert it into a cUrl request to use it through prompt command or import into Postman.

[image]

if the "KEY" field is empty it won't work.

Here is what I tried :
`curl --header "Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded" \ --request POST \ --data '{"resource":"https://xxxxx.com/resources","scope": "openid","client_id":"xxx-xxx-x-xxx","client_secret":"xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx"}' \ https://xxxxx-xxxxx.com/api/token`

in Postman the result is "Bad request".

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a POSTMAN request to Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432735/converting-a-postman-request-to-curl)

Answer (score 1):

You can get any request as curl from postman. It will be generated automatically. You should follow below two images for getting curl request code.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Fantastic ! thanks !!

Comment: yes. This is a built in feature of postman. really awesome

Comment: It is working with Postman but unfortunately it does't work when I copy/paste the curl code generated by Postman into a Windows command prompt.  At the end I just try to get a response from an API.

Comment: its working in linux .

Comment: but windows may create issues.

Comment: This finally works : curl --location --request POST "https://xxxxx.com/api/token?grant_type=client_credentials&resource=https://xxxxxxxxx.com/resources&scope=openid&client_id=xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxe&client_secret=xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx" --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  . The import thing is to put double quote instead of single one.  --location is even not necessary and rhe request is as simple as that.