# How to fix the error "multipart: NextPart: bufio: buffer full"? I am using fetch post request to upload image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to fix the error "multipart: NextPart: bufio: buffer full"? I am using fetch post request to upload image.

My site has a functionality to upload profile picture, I do it with fetch post request, here is the code of request:

```
async function uploadAvatar(data, token) {
    return  await fetch(`${apiBase}upload/avatar`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryEmKNDsBKjB7QEqu',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body: data
    });
}
```

Here is the form submitter handler function:

```
const onUploadAvatar = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(e.target);
    try {
        const response = await uploadAvatar(formData, localStorage.getItem('token'));
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log('ok');
        } else response.json().then((res) => {
            createError(res.message);
        })

    } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to submit a form gives an error with the message "multipart: NextPart: bufio: buffer full"

I don't know how to fix this error and what does it mean

Comment: Check https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26707

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue with Postman but then I tried to make the request with cURL and it worked. I'd suggest doing that as a workaround if possible.

You can find more about how to convert a postman request to cURL at [Converting a Postman request to curl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49432735/11107541).

Comment: How should that work? Should cURL be integrated into the app?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35308307)

Comment: @possum how is this link-only?