# Post request works in postman but not in python code

Tags: python, python-requests, postman

I am trying to post a request on a website that requires credentials. I have used postman and sync with the browser using interceptor (google extension) to make use of the cookies stored correctly in postman. I have succeeded in posting the request in postman and here is the settings I did.
[image]

When trying to copy the code of the Python requests package, I got an invalid response `404` and something went wrong.
Here's the python code I got from Postman (not working)

```
import requests

url = "https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/execFileUpload2"

payload = {'selectAser': '211053300',
'phoneNo': '55075052',
'selectAsed': '120987470-1',
'comReg': '',
'bankType': '1850',
'attachments': '(binary)',
'searchType': '0745'}
files=[

]
headers = {
  'Cookie': 'BNES_JSESSIONID=FBVxGgtjjJhDGmcnG/XOglUeuJlG/mwpJH9+ICQw/bL3/2Y383HWR4f+WzRXsJBG5jHf33qCsgMBOHLeTKxJRBwlkrkKE1tGbdywVgdikWhC4VcCUd1yIIYJBFm4m/60lfkGqvgk+UfaMbPKe3CUVRvsTaMCLn+A; BNIS___utm_is1=834onz3cMbm6+rxfXql7Q9R5wUqKP9h0Og9waF061RytqqFpbicKoodJVczfRblgLKkNejO9xULfy/gV59QKOKqOE5nH62HC/3yuYJehn8hT5JL0Trtl1Q==; BNIS___utm_is2=h3TrzcqVULgLWXXvNz3L2bQtrG+U/tHgaCBTF5MLDA6zaHEpzzwCy9Rj99RJySZUYmO8bQuFJ6s=; BNIS___utm_is3=xl2RfksMuxdJJrgDWe3RlTXaGAMcCXNp8jk39UeD37JWegODHQm0CVYCakYal9jUfWovaY2FrKriBIFNQOFbyIxcgMpHKnERXJrFCsvLKrmZNPgeZdMezA==; BNIS_vid=dVdYD1HKY4P0pa5whnuuvLgo71u2130LdG9wpcgfK0yYw3B1mLAfK2pzLr7+xPH1h3PVudRNDGJQHyVY0Y9fVfhte25qE3ArdMOHRB4jcyMGq/9iCsU5goBa1Q2hVs/8Fqd53PjKs7hT81XeYQ8Jtani11zEpPgkw70aLejHmSSykk8nACMnKMr0zP4RqoujmqEbAHE3+e6Odf2XSkBCWh3jPiyUqWmU4zYGail1N6A=; JSESSIONID=6ZLK74MAMrYOWAb39OQ7EYLHtt9GjRFzwvgwACd9idbb76Fe7q4p!669384774'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

This is the response I got

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html dir="rtl">
 <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
        <title>::بوابة العدل الالكترونية::</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Styles/NMaster.css" />

        <style type="text/css">
                <!--
                        H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;}
                        PRE, TT {border: 1px dotted #525D76}
                        A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}
                -->
        </style>
 </head>
 <body>
     <h1 style="text-align:center;">حدث خطأ ما </h1>

 </body>
</html>
```

Here are some snapshots (may help us)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welp, the status code and message doesn't mean anything in this I guess. Can it be because you are trying to register twice?

Comment: But in postman I have clicked on Send button several times and got the same response `Registered Successully`

Comment: I tried sending a request but can't establish a connection. Could you try with `allow_redirects=True` in the `request` function, since it redirects...

Comment: @YasserKhalil Use a tool such as https://curlconverter.com/ and see if it works. To get the curl - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432735/converting-a-postman-request-to-curl

Comment: @MendelG From Postman to cURL to Python. Hmm. In the past Insomnia gave me similar problems, this approach may work.

Answer (score 2):

It's challenging to provide a precise solution without examining the file you're working with.

If your request functions correctly in Postman but encounters issues in Python, it's likely that there's a discrepancy in your Python code. A handy approach to troubleshooting this would be to:

1. Obtain the `CURL` command from Postman. See: [Converting a Postman request to cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432735/converting-a-postman-request-to-curl).
2. Once you have the `CURL` command, you can then convert it into Python code using a tool like [curlconverter.com](https://curlconverter.com/).

By comparing the converted Python code with your existing Python code, you should be able to pinpoint the problem

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have copied the curl from developer tools as bash and paste in the website recommended for me and it converted to python `https://curlconverter.com/`

Comment: Yes, I have put the code in my question as an update. But need more help.

Comment: I've now rollbacked your question..

Answer (score 1):

code looks correct, but there are several things that you can try with your code.

1. try using sessions
2. instead of data you can try with json parameter in post method.

   ```
    import requests
    sess = requests.Session()
    url = "https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/execFileUpload2"
    payload = {'selectAser': '211053300',
     'phoneNo': '55075052',
     'selectAsed': '120987470-1',
     'comReg': '',
     'bankType': '1850',
     'attachments': '(binary)',
     'searchType': '0745'}

   files=[]
   headers = {
     #mention a proper header according to website
   }

   response = sess.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload,
    files=files)
   #Or you can try below one also whichever works for you
   response = sess.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload, files=files

   print(response.text)
   ```

Comment: What about cookies., did you implement them in the code? if possible put the headers to know what was wrong with my first code.

Comment: session from request automatically handle and store the cookies

Comment: What about headers? !! I have to use cookies now to test. later I will use session.