# Uber API issue : Getting error while using this code. SSL certificate self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: uber-api

I am new to Uber API, I just started exploring the Uber API's.
I have downloaded the complete Uber API repository from https://github.com/stevenmaguire/uber-php/issues/17

I have downloaded the complete repository using the composer. It shows that all dependencies were downloaded successfully. but when I am using the API, I am getting this error

> Blockquote"SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Please help me in this, I have raised this issue 8 days back on the Github no one is replied.

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYpAM.png)

Thanks in Advance.
Rakesh

Here is my code`

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Stevenmaguire\Uber\Client(array(
    'access_token' => '********',
    'server_token' => '********',
    'use_sandbox'  => false, // optional, default false
    'version'      => 'v1.2', // optional, default 'v1.2'
    'locale'       => 'en_US', // optional, default 'en_US'
));

$products = $client->getProducts(array(
    'latitude' => '41.85582993',
    'longitude' => '-87.62730337'
));

var_dump($products);

?>
```

`

Comment: Please post your code as actual text and not a linked screenshot image. [Also, see answer here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187946/60-ssl-certificate-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chainbool/23585500#23585500)

Comment: I have update the code.

Comment: You should use a valid ssl certificate. You can create one for free usings letsencrypt - https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: Hello Dustin, thanks for the reply. Can you please elaborate the steps which I need to follow. Thanks in Advanced.!!