# WORDPRESS : cURL error 60: SSL certificate

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, curl

I'm currently building a Wordpress install under a debian server. I install PHP7, curl and Apache2

While I'm trying to install new extension I have this error message :

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

I try to modify the php.ini with this, after reading some post treating similar issue :

```
curl.cainfo = /etc/php7.0/cacert.pem
```

But I'm still facing the problem even with restart apache.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check file path `/etc/php7.0/cacert.pem` where it located

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curl error 60, SSL certificate prðblem: self signed certificate in certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187946/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-pr%c3%b0blem-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-c)

Comment: I check the file path, and it's good :/

Answer (score 21):

Disable SSL verification within your testing site.

You can do this by adding this line into the file

Appearance > Theme Editor > functions.php or

/wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/functions.php:

```
add_filter('https_ssl_verify', '__return_false');
```

Only add this on a testing site, never on a live site.

Answer (score 14):

set 'sslverify' to false to fix the cURL error 60: SSL certificate in WordPress wp_remote_get request.

```
wp_remote_get($url, array('sslverify' => FALSE));
```

Comment: Where to add this?

Comment: Very nice solution! it solved me the problem! Brilliant!

Answer (score 6):

WordPress uses it's own CA bundle, located in `WP/wp-includes/certificates`.

The CA bundle that was shipped with WordPress up until recently was outdated, as discussed in this issue: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/45807.

Setting `sslverify` to `false` is not recommended, and instead you can download an updated version of the bundle, https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/tree/master/wp-includes/certificates and replace it in the wordpress folder.

Comment: The CA bundle from the Github link you stated did not work for me (restarted local apache and everything). Only settings 'sslverify' => FALSE did...

Answer (score 4):

Based on my recent experience, I believe that the message "*self signed certificate* in certificate chain" tells you the issue exactly - which is that whichever SSL site you are trying to access has a certificate in the chain that is not in the bunch that is referenced by **cacert.pem**.

This makes sense because the error reports that it is a *self-signed* certificate..  i.e. It would never be included in the downloaded cacert.pem file.

My solution was to get a *Base64* encoded file containing the certificate chain of the site that I am trying to access.

```
    How to: Use a browser to access the site you are trying to access, click the 
    certificate part of the address (usually to the left of the address box with 
    a lock icon) and the click on whatever your interface supports to see the 
    list of certificates in the chain.  Manually export those certificates to a 
    text file.
```

Then append this text file with a text editor to the list of certificates (cacert.pem) that PHP is using for CURL actions.

---

You mention WordPress.. WordPress v4.9.6 has a bundle of certificates that it specifically references when it is upgrading or installing plugins at ./***WordPress Instance***\wp-includes\certificates.  My stop-gap solution was to append the text file above (containing the local self signed-certificate chain) to the *ca-bundle.crt* file that you will find in that location.

One caveat - when you upgrade WordPress it will overwrite the *ca-bundle.crt* file, so you will have to re-add them - unless someone has a better solution..?

Comment: This exactly is what worked for me. I knew the issue was it being self-signed, I just didn't know how to convince WordPress that this was okay. Your solution was the only one that worked. For anyone who is having this issue on a local install of WordPress, this is the solution.

Comment: underrated answer this saved my day, cheers

Answer (score 2):

In case someone come across same issue with their WordPress installation on Local Machine, by adding [`http_request_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/http_request_args/) filter did the trick for me

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Local Dev CaFile
 * Plugin URI: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44632619/881743
 * Description: Another solution for `SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain apache` error for your local development
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: John Doe
 * Author URI: https://stackoverflow.com/
 * License: WTFPL
 */

add_filter( 'http_request_args', function ( $args ) {
    if ( getenv('WP_ENV') !== 'development' ) {
        return $args;
    } 

    $args['sslcertificates'] = ini_get( 'curl.cainfo' ) ?? $args['sslcertificates'];

    return $args;
}, 0, 1 );
```

and save it in `path/to/wp-content/plugins/dev-plugin.php` and activate the plugin from wp-admin, or optionally you could put it in your [`WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/).

Hope that helps
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Download this file http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Use your file's location in 
`openssl.cafile=c:/cacert.pem`

Reference - https://github.com/auth0/auth0-PHP#i-am-getting-curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-on-windows

Comment: @Nathan30 wordpress version?

Comment: Latest Wordpress 4.8

Comment: @Nathan30 Just download the 4.7.5 version of wordpress & copy /wp-includes/certificates/ca-bundle.crt to your server. Keep backup of your old file too.

Comment: Did it, and still remain the same problem :/

Comment: Where do I have to put it ? ON which wordpress file ?

Comment: @Nathan30 got no leads man. May be try reinstalling Wordpress. If you find any solution please update me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade from wp-cli 2.4 => 2.5 helped me. (with installing this https://github.com/wp-cli/profile-command )

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers here worked for me (and may not work for people using Let's Encrypt certificates on their servers). I found that  recently (Sept 30,2021 ) the Let's Encrypt Cretificates expired DST Root CA X3. In addition to the curl error 60 I also had Rest API errors and inability to updated plugins in wordpress.   It is possible to update these in the wordpress installation:

The patch is available here  and should be available with Wordpress 5.9 (December 2021) if not earlier:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/51883/trunk/src/wp-includes/certificates/ca-bundle.crt

Answer (score 0):

For Wordpress you can use like this:

```
$url = "YOUR_ENDPOINT";
$args = array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Authorization' => 'HASH_HERE'
        ),
        'sslverify' => FALSE,
        'data' => array(
            'campaign_id' => $campaign_id
        )
    );

$response = wp_remote_get($url, $args);
$body     = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently because our network does the ssl proxy trick.
We had a custom CA bundle that included our internal cert.
That was bundled up in the /etc/pki folders, so I just symlinked to it:
ln -s /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt /wp-includes/certificates/

Now it stays updated whenever I update the system.