# "Download failed. cURL error 60: SSL certificate: self signed certificate."

Tags: wordpress

I tried to install some plugins on a theme in wordpress and this message came up

> Download failed. cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed
>   certificate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curl error 60, SSL certificate prðblem: self signed certificate in certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187946/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-pr%c3%b0blem-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-c)

Comment: i don't know how to fix it...i went on a forum on wordpress which said to deactivate windows firewall...but it didn't work.....so tried downloading the cacert.pem file and put it in the ssl folder....but it didn't work either....also, i didn't find any other solution

Comment: If you even want some help.. clarify your question. It's to general. Supply your setup, OS, what kind of installation and what you have already done in a organized post. This is to summier to help you, by anyone.