# How to get the list of subscribers from drip account with curl?

Tags: php, curl

I have been trying to get the list of subscribers from drip account. I am trying to do so with the curl php I am unable to do so.

**Official example**

```
curl -H 'User-Agent: Your App Name (www.yourapp.com)' \
  -u f4ff6a200e850131dca1040cce1ee51a: \
  -d status=active \
  https://api.getdrip.com/v2/9999999/campaigns
```

**My Code**

```
$TOKEN='f69444e104aea5b77a969bb313852dc1';
$ch = curl_init('https://api.getdrip.com/v2/1186104/subscribers');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'TestApp (laflechee@gmail.com)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Authorization: Bearer ' . $TOKEN
));
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
```

Comment: WHat error/data do you get?

Comment: @David i don't get any error it returns blank response

Comment: curl_error($ch) returns blank too ?

Comment: yes it returns blank

Comment: SOrry I edited my comment. I meant curl_error, not curl_exec

Comment: it returns this error 
SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Comment: Have alook there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187946/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-issue-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-cha

Comment: I checked that link but i think drip guys are not providing any certificate file for this.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

**I am adding a new subscriber in drip with the below code. You can follow it.**

```
$ch = curl_init();
//YOUR-ACCOUNT-ID replace it with your account id
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.getdrip.com/v2/YOUR-ACCOUNT-ID/subscribers');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$data = array(
                'subscribers' => array(
                    array( 
                        'email'      => 'myemail@domain.com',
                        'first_name' => 'Mohsin',
                        'last_name'  => 'raza' 
                    ),
                ),
            );
$post = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
//YOUR-API-TOKEN-HERE replace it with your api-token
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'YOUR-API-TOKEN-HERE' . ':' . '');

$headers = array();
//replace with your app name and registered domain with drip account
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: YOUR-APP-NAME (www.your-domain.com)';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result; 
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```