# PHP cURL (SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain)

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, php-curl

When making a php cURL request in production, I am getting the following error: Problem with SSL certificate: self-signed certificate in the certificate chain. Since in my local machine it has worked normally.

Here is the code used:

```
$curl = curl_init();
 
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    $authorization,
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is like it says: the URL you are calling uses a self signed certificate and since self-signed certificate are unsafe, you are getting that error message.

If you are OK with this unsafe connection you can ignore the error by adding the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST option. However, you want to consider to add a valid certificate for safety.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP CURL, the error is probably caused by not having an up-to-date bundle of CA root certificates. This is typically a text file with a bunch of cryptographic signatures that curl uses to verify a host’s SSL certificate.

You need to make sure that your installation of PHP has one of these files, and that it’s up to date (otherwise download one here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html).

After download, upload it to your server, or root folder, or just anywhere accessible within your host account, then set in php.ini:

```
curl.cainfo = <absolute_path_to> cacert.pem
```

If you do not have access to the php.ini, and would want to set it at runtime, use this option in CURL pipline:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert.pem");
```

(where `$ch = curl_init();`):

[More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187946/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-issue-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-cha)