# Why I'm getting cURL error 60 when uploading images to Cloudinary?

Tags: laravel, curl, cloudinary

I'm using [cloudinary-labs/cloudinary-laravel](https://github.com/cloudinary-labs/cloudinary-laravel) package to upload images to Cloudinary using the following code:

```
$result = Cloudinary::upload($request->file('photo')->getRealPath());
```

but I get cURL error 60 with the following details:

```
"message": "cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/{MY-CLOUD-NAME}/image/upload",
"exception": "GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\RequestException",
"file": "F:\\open-source-projects\\soora\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlFactory.php",
"line": 211,
```

At first, I thought I knew the solution because I've faced the same error in another project (but using AWS instead) so I downloaded **cacert.pem** file and placed it in the **php.ini** file, **but I'm still getting the same error.**

Comment: You may want to check the answer in this SO thread - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187946/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-issue-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-cha

Comment: @RoeeBen-Ari Thanks for your reply, but as I mentioned above, I've tried the popular and accepted solution (getting an up-to-date bundle of CA root certificates). But, unfortunately, I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: Hi @Mahdi, I am having this same issue while trying to upload an image to Cloudinary. Have you been able to fix this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing (cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain) is most likely related to the Root certificate bundles on your server making the request - where those Root certificate bundles are out of date.

To resolve the issue, as a first step, please check and update the certificate bundles on your server.