# PHP cURL error: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate

Tags: php, .net, macos, ssl, curl

Long story short, I had to reinstall php 7.4 on my Mac.  I have a php webapp that hits a .NET API.  Prior to the reinstall of php, I was able to hit a locally running version of my API at https://localhost:5001 using cURL in php but now I get a response code of 0 with this error:

```
Curl error: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
```

If I point the same php code to my production API, everything works fine.  I am able to successfully hit the local version of the API with Postman.

I tried the accepted answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187946/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-issue-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-cha) but it did not work for me even after restarting apache and my computer.  I tried both the `php.ini` and runtime approaches but neither solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should append the public key of your self signed certificate to the cacert.pem file. Then either of the solutions (setting `curl.cainfo` in php.ini OR explicitly specifying the path to the cacert.pem file using `CURLOPT_CAINFO`) proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23585500/3219919) should work just fine.

Make sure you respect the format of the cacert.pem file when adding your public key.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much for your help.  For anyone who might be reading this later, use this command to get your localhost public key:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:5001
```

Comment: @AdamLeVasseur Can you please explain a little more  how you made that work, I am stuck on the same problem.

Comment: @pyrogrammer
With my API running locally on port 5001 I ran the command specified above in a terminal window.  Then I pasted the certificate from that output to the bottom of cacert.pem.