# Cloudinary PHP SDK - cURL error 60 uploading image

Tags: php, ssl, curl, cloudinary

I am working on a project with Symfony 6, PHP 8 and trying to upload images to Cloudinary using its PHP SDK, `cloudinary/cloudinary_php` version 2.7.1 and following [these docs](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_integration).

I am creating a Cloudinary instance as

```
$cloudinary = new Cloudinary([
    'cloud' => [
        'cloud_name' => 'my_name',
        'api_key' => 'my_api_key',
        'api_secret' => 'my_api_secret']
]);
```

and then uploading my base64 file as

```
$result = $cloudinary->uploadApi()->upload($base64Image);
```

Doing this I get the following `GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\RequestException`:

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/oralec/image/upload
```

### What I tried

I ended up in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187946/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-issue-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-cha) (and others of the same nature) where the accepted answer is always to download cacert.pem from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html and the set your modify your php.ini file with

```
curl.cainfo = <absolute_path_to> cacert.pem
```

which in my case is

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\php\cacert.pem"
```

But this makes no difference in the exception I get. I tried modifying php.ini, php.ini-development and php.ini-production, just in case.

I also tried installing vendors like `https://github.com/composer/ca-bundle` and `https://github.com/paragonie/certainty`, again with no success at all.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Any chance you didn't restart your web server after changing php.ini?

Comment: Make sure the webserver can access the cacert.pem file. Check rights and owner/group.

Comment: You could also set curl  option `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false. I don't know how it's done using Guzzle. This is a workaround.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions! I eventually found that Symfony was using a php located in a different folder than the one I wrote (Instead of `C:\php` it was `C:\xampp\php`). Changing php.ini in that location fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found that Symfony was using a php located in a different folder than the one I wrote (Instead of `C:\php` it was `C:\xampp\php`).

Changing php.ini in that location fixed the issue.