# Test DeepL api from localhost

Tags: php, api, ssl, self-signed-certificate, deepl

I'm trying to test the DeepL API on my local machine but I'm getting this error in PHP :

```
DeepL\ConnectionException: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain.
```

My code is simple :

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use DeepL\DeepLException;
use DeepL\Translator;

try
{
    $authKey = "HIDDEN_KEY";
    $translator = new Translator($authKey);
    $result = $translator->translateText('Hello, world!', null, 'fr');
    echo $result->text; // Should print "Bonjour, le monde!"
} catch (DeepLException $e)
{
    echo "KO";
    error_log($e);
}
```

I realize this probably won't happen on the actual server but isn't there any way to test the API locally first ?

Comment: how can you get an api key fro a free account plz ?

Answer (score 0):

As the DeepL PHP library uses cURL to make HTTP-requests, this could be the same problem as answered here: [Curl error 60, SSL certificate issue: self signed certificate in certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187946/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-issue-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-cha/23585500#23585500).

Try making sure that your installation of PHP has a CA root certificate, and that it’s up to date.