# SSL Issues Using cURL to Access APIs

Tags: php, api, curl

I have been trying to gain access to a couple of APIs from two different parties using `cURL` but have been experiencing a consistent issue. When I submit a request to either party I receive the following error:

> SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

I am attempting to reach these APIs from my localhost which is currently WAMP.

Here is how I am attempting to gain access:

```
$ch = curl_init($target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_error($ch)) {
    var_dump(curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

I am confused as to why I am recieving an error because I can use the following code to access the APIs using `file_get_contents()`

```
$opts = [
    "http" => [
        "header" => implode("\r\n", $headers)
    ],
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => true,
        "verify_peer_name" => true
    ]
];

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$response = file_get_contents($target_url, NULL, $context);

var_dump($response);
```

Edit: These requests contain sensitive information so TLS/SSL is a must.

Edit: `$target_url = 'https://*3rd Party API*/target';`

Edit: **there is no proxy**

Comment: can you clarify if `$target_url` is your WAMP server or if it is a 3rd party api and if the url starts with http or https?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690173/post-request-with-a-self-signed-certificate