# curl command line to PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, paypal

How do I translate this commandline PayPal cURL request `--insecure`

```
curl -s --insecure 
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: api_username" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: api_password" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: api_signature" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV" 
-H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: app_id"
```

I know I will place `-H` values to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: api_username', 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: api_password'));
```

But I am not sure with the `--insecure`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html :

> -k, --insecure: (SSL) This option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL connections and transfers. All SSL connections are
>   attempted to be made secure by using the CA certificate bundle
>   installed by default. This makes all connections considered "insecure"
>   fail unless -k, --insecure is used.

Looking further at [reading SSL page with CURL (php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521418/reading-ssl-page-with-curl-php), this tells you that you have to set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to FALSE. This basically overrides the "security checks".

I think that's what you need to mirror the `--insecure` command line option.