# curl always returning false

Tags: php, curl

The following code always echos false. Am I missing something?

```
$url = "https://www.google.nl/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
if(curl_exec($ch)) {
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [reading SSL page with CURL (php)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521418/reading-ssl-page-with-curl-php)

Comment: `echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);` could be useful for debugging in situations like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this **`cURL`** param. That is because , Google runs on Secure HTTP.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```