# Problems authenticating against Adform PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to authenticate against Adforms API, but am getting an error when I try.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what is wrong? Here are some details: 
- The script is being run on a fresh install of EasyPHP (with cUrl enabled). 
- The same script is being launched from another computer, on which it works just fine (it runs on a mac - I'm on Windows).
- User and password below are fake, of course.

The code fails with this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'We did not get a HTTP 200 when retrieving a ticket. We recieved this: { "url": "https:\/\/api.adform.com\/Services\/Security\/Login", "content_type": null, "http_code": 0, "header_size": 0, "request_size": 0, "filetime": -1, "ssl_verify_result": 1, "redirect_count": 0, "total_time": 0.187, "namelookup_time": 0.14, "connect_time": 0.156, "pretransfer_time": 0, "size_upload": 0, "size_download": 0, "speed_download": 0, "speed_upload": 0, "download_content_length": -1, "upload_content_length": -1, "starttransfer_time": 0, "redirect_time": 0, "redirect_url": "", "primary_ip": "37.157.5.109", "certinfo": [], "primary_port": 443, "local_ip": "192.168.1.7", "local_port": 49460 }false' in C:\Users\Mikkel\PHP\adformdsp\adf-ticket.php:60 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\Mikkel\PHP\adformdsp\adf-ticket.php(66): Adform->ticket() #1 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Mikkel\PHP\adformdsp\adf-ticket.php on line 60
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php

class Adform
{
    protected $user;
    protected $pass;

    public function __construct($user, $pass)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;
    }

    # Authenticate to Adform by retrieving a ticket
    public function ticket()
    {
        $curl = curl_init();

        $credentials = json_encode(array(
            'UserName' => $this->user, 
            'Password' => $this->pass
            ));

        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.adform.com/Services/Security/Login', 
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $credentials,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json'),
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            );

        curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);

        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        if(curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == '200')
        {
            $header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
            $header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
            $body = json_decode(substr($result, $header_size), TRUE);

            curl_close($curl);

            if(array_key_exists('Ticket', $body))
            {
                # We successfully retrieved a ticket!
                return $body['Ticket'];
            }
            else
            {
                # We connected to Adforms server but did not get a ticket..
                throw new Exception('We connected to Adforms server but did not retrieve a ticket. We recieved this: ' . $result);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            #We did not get a HTTP 200 from the request to Adform..
            throw new Exception('We did not get a HTTP 200 when retrieving a ticket. We recieved this: ' . json_encode(curl_getinfo($curl), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
        }   
    }
}

$adform = new Adform("notsharing","thatwithyouguys");
echo $adform->ticket();
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Ding

Answer (score 0):

1. Check $result for error

   `$result = curl_exec($curl);
   if($result === false) { 
       echo curl_error($curl);
       echo curl_errno($curl);
   }`

or better way: [curl_exec() always returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227909/curl-exec-always-returns-false)

2. In my case the problem was: "*SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"*
   Solution that hepled me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21377070/5569198